# Twilio serverless function to send sms at the end of a voice call

Tags: twilio, sms, serverless

I am trying to send an SMS at the end of a voice call by using a Twilio Function that is triggered on the status change event. The function is triggered and any other log messages that I include get logged correctly. However, the SMS is not delivered.  I have even hard coded the `From` and `To` numbers but that did not help.

I am using a trial account but have made sure that the To number is on the verified sender list.
I don't see any errors in the logs. Its as if the `messages.create` statement did not exist. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {

  const twilioClient = context.getTwilioClient();

  twilioClient.messages
    .create({
      body: 'Service activation request',
      from: event.To,
      to: event.From
    })
    .then(message => console.log("Message delivered"));

return callback(null, cookieData.conversation.length);
};
```

I used the Twilio SMS testing interface and was successful in delivering the SMS. So I know my number is capable of sending an SMS. I am expecting the above code to use the SMS api to deliver the sms but I am certainly missing something. I even tried to use the messaging service id as a parameter but that did not help.

Comment: You could try sending the text to another Twilio number to verify if your carrier/phone company is blocking the text. And, did you complete the 10DLC process? https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/1260800720410-What-is-A2P-10DLC-

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is a problem with the return statement, specifically with the variable, `cookieData`.

Please try the following solution:

```js
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  const twilioClient = context.getTwilioClient();

  twilioClient.messages
    .create({
      body: 'Service activation request',
      from: event.To,
      to: event.From
    })
    .then(message => {
      console.log("Message delivered");
      return callback(null, event.body.length);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error("Error sending message:", err);
      return callback(err); // Return the error to the caller
    });
};
```

Comment: Hmm, I have to say it is working now. The main change I made was change the return statement to be part of the .then and .catch functions as per your example. The cookieData was fine as I was assigning that earilier in the code. I am a bit confused why I have to have the return as part of the api function callback. This would mean, I can only execute 1 api function call in any Twilio function. Anyway, it is working so thanks for that.

Comment: Yes, FaaS (like Twilio Functions) terminate once the function has been completed, i.e. after the return statement. Since `messages.create` is async, this function was most likely not yet executed when the Function terminated.
PS: You could also use `await` if you'd like to avoid the `then` and `catch`